# Quotes in PDF bookmarks when using polyglossia

Tags: babel, polyglossia, bookmarks, csquotes

I am creating a multilingual document, using `polyglossia`. I would like to include quoted text in a section title, using `csquotes`, and I would also like to have a PDF bookmark tree in the final file, one bookmark per section, using `bookmark`. Finally, I am also using `polyglossia`'s babel-style shorthands (`babelshorthands=true`).

The following MWE fails:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
\section{This works}
\section{\enquote{This breaks}}
\end{document}
```

The error message is as follows:

```
! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.10 \section{\enquote{This breaks}}
[...]
```

Googling has led me to conclude that the `babel` shorthands are at issue here (indeed, not enabling them gets rid of the error), and that I should disable the `"` shorthand before the section title, then re-enable it, using `\shorthandoff` and `\shorthandon` respectively (these are `babel` commands also supplied by `polyglossia`; in fact, `babel`'s own documentation specifically recommends these for the above error):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
\section{This works}
\shorthandoff{"}%
\section{\enquote{This breaks}}
\shorthandon{"}%
\end{document}
```

However, this still results in the same error message as above.

Using `babel` itself instead of `polyglossia` works; the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
\section{This works}
\shorthandoff{"}%
\section{\enquote{This breaks}}
\shorthandon{"}%
\end{document}
```

produces the desired output without any errors. Alternatively, using `polyglossia` also works (even without disabling the `"` shorthand) so long as the `bookmark` package isn't loaded.

My questions are, thus:

1. is this a bug in `polyglossia` that I should report (`\shorthandoff` and `\shorthandon` not working as desired), and/or in `bookmark`?, and
2. since I would prefer to keep using both `polyglossia` and `babel` shorthands while also retaining the quote in the section title and the PDF bookmarks, is there another work-around for the original error that would allow this, or is this a case of "given X, pick any (X-1)"?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) the issue here is the bookmarks, it generally does not like handling latex macros,  the normal `\texorpdfstring{for PDF}{for bookmark}` works with your example. Generally bookmarks want unicode only and thus attempts to filter away left behind macros. And it probably does not like active chars one bit.

Comment: With `babel` in place of `polyglossia` you don't need `\shorthandoff`. But the bookmarks quotes are not the German ones (whether or not using `\shorthandoff`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the language later. The option `babelshorthands=true` makes the shorthand directly active and so disturbs packages loaded later:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}
\begin{document}
\section{This works}
\section{\enquote{This breaks}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There should be a tag for `load-order` or `package-loading` or `package-order` or something like that. It's pretty prominently important in some cases.